# Is "shined" correct? If so, is "he shined X on the tree" also correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-tense

Recently, I overhead a former professor of mine use the word *shined*, a word that makes me grammatically uncomfortable.  She used it as following: "Then, after we shined a light on the other ball, what happened?..."  My first question is: Is using *shined* mainstream, over what sounds better to my ear, *shone*?  If so, is there any historical flip-flopping between the two usages?  Secondly, if *shined* is in fact legit, can it be used transitively?  Saying something like,

> The light shined all throughout the night.

while odd, doesn't sound as bad to my ear as,

> He shined the light on the ball throughout the night.

The latter sounds quite bad to my ear.  Indeed, à propos the original question, can *shone* — the better sounding alternative to my ear — be used transitively?

Comment: I agree that "shone" sounds better for these examples, but what about other meanings, such as "shined my shoes"? In that case "shone my shoes" sounds wrong to my ear. Also, "I shone at linguistics"? That sounds wrong, too.

Comment: This seems to be an American/British split. Looking at Google Ngrams, a small fraction of American usage is *shined* (maybe 15%), but it seems to be very rarely used in Britain. My guess, from a small sample, is that in Britain the **only** time the past tense of *shine* is *shined* is when it means *polish* (e.g., he shined my shoes). Can anybody from the U.K. confirm this?

Comment: Even stranger, it appears that in the U.K., the past tense of *shine his shoes* is *polished his shoes*. See [this Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shine+his+shoes%2C+polish+his+shoes%2Cpolished+his+shoes%2Cshined+his+shoes%2C+shone+his+shoes&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), which seems to show that in the U.K., people use both *shine* and *polish* with *shoes* in the present tense, but only say *polished his shoes* in the past tense (presumably to avoid using the execrable Americanism *shined*).

Comment: @Peter Shor: As a Brit I confirm all you say. I'd just about accept "he shined shoes for a living", but probably because I think of that as an occupation in the US a century ago (when and where they talked funny anyway). I'd rather have "polished" in all other contexts - except lights, which should always be *shone*, never *shined* (truly execrable word, as you say! :).

Comment: Should it be pointed out that in the U.K., *shone* rhymes with *gone,* while in the U.S., *shone* rhymes with *bone*?

Comment: Really?  Seán is pronounced the same as shone?

Comment: @GEdgar In Britain, yes, I believe so: there all three of  *Sean*, *Shawn*, and *shone* are identical homophones pronounced with the CLOTH vowel, so /ʃɒn/.  Most Americans do not have that vowel (well, not as a distinct phoneme) and so would pronouns *Sean* and *Shawn* as either /ʃɑn/ or /ʃɔːn/, depending on where they sit along the *cot–caught* merger continuum, and would pronounce *shone* the same as they (we) do *shown*, so both of those are /ʃoʊn/ with a diphthong. So in North America, *shone* and *shown* are the same, and *Sean* and *Shawn* are the same, but those two pairs are different.

Comment: This may be a bit off-topic, but with regard to the occupation of shoe-shining in the United States today, the activity commonly (and perhaps usually) does not involve the application of any shoe polish to the shoes; rather, the person doing the shining simply holds a cotton cloth tightly in both hands and vigorously rubs the portion of the cloth that lies between the two hands on the surfaces of each shoe. I've often thought that "shoe massage" might be a more accurate term for this operation. In U.S. English, "polishing shoes" refers to treating them with liquid or paste polish.

Comment: @tchrist - Erm, no. In Britain, *Sean*, *Shawn* and *shorn* are all pronounced the same (to rhyme with *borne* or *bourne*). This is different to *shone*, which rhymes with the German city *Bonn*. And *shown* is another pronunciation again, rhyming with *own*.

Answer (score 10):

The [Grammarist](http://www.grammarist.com/usage/shined-shone/) has an opinion on this issue, writing that the difference between the two is as follows:

> The verb shine has two main definitions: (1) to emit light (intransitive), and (2) to cause to gleam by polishing (transitive). As an intransitive verb (definition 1), shine makes shone in its past-tense, perfect-tense, and past-participle forms.  As a transitive verb (definition 2), it makes shined.

He says that the following are *incorrect* uses:

- But the one that shined the brightest was simply topped with a perfect beurre blanc and a touch of caviar. [The Atlantic]
- What’s more, one of the numbers reflected light differently when Smith’s headlights shined on it. [Winnipeg Free Press]

The following are *correct* uses:

- A 13-year-old boy needed hospital treatment after a laser pen was shone in his eyes in Eastwood. [BBC News]
- A return trip to the store shone the light on what I needed: Leeks. [Denver Post]
- Shearer doesn’t look like he belongs ensconced in dark-green leather and spit-shined oak . . . [Washington Post]
- They shined the marble. [National Post]

So if the verb is [intransitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb), you should use *shone*. If it is [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb), you should use *shined*. In your examples:

> The light shined all throughout the night.

Here, *shine* is intransitive, since you're not talking about shining the light *on* something. So it may actually be better to say "the light shone all throughout the night".

In your second example, "He shined the light on the ball throughout the night" this is actually correct because the verb is transitive.

Prescriptivists like the Grammarist would say that no, you can't use *shone* transitively. However, in the argument that people could still understand a transitive *shone*, you *could* use it. It is up to you which side you'd want to take on this.

Comment: One of your examples is a transitive use of shone: "A return trip to the store shone the light on what I needed: Leeks." (and perfectly correct).

Answer (score 5):

[Merriam-Webster's dictionary of English Usage](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA846&dq=%22shined%22&hl=en&ei=TdVYTq_YAaXe0QHvtdmrDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22shined%22&f=false) says that in England, in the 16th century, *shined* and *shone* were competing past tenses for *shine*. It also explains that since then, the British and the American usages have diverged. In the rest of the post, I summarize the usage explained in this text (using some of their examples). I have estimated the frequency of these usages myself using Google Ngrams.

In the U.K., *shined* appears to be used only for the sense of *polish,* mainly for shoes, and even then only occasionally. See [this Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shine+his+shoes%2C+polish+his+shoes%2Cpolished+his+shoes%2Cshined+his+shoes%2C+shone+his+shoes&year_start=1980&year_end=2010&corpus=6&smoothing=3) for evidence that even for shoes, while Brits are willing to use *shine* in the present tense, they avoid using *shined* in the past tense, preferring *polished.*

In America, for the sun, *shone* is [almost always used](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=sun+shined%2C+sun+shone&year_start=1980&year_end=2010&corpus=5&smoothing=3). For other sources of light, when *shine* is used as an intransitive verb, the past tense is *shone* [maybe 90% of the time:](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=light+shined+on%2Clight+shone+on&year_start=1980&year_end=2010&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

> That hard fierce light of publicity that everybody hates shone on everything he did.

But when it is used transitively (somebody shined something), [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shined+the+light%2Cshone+the+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=10) shows that somewhere around 40% of Americans use *shined.* This usage started somewhere around 1940, and has been growing in frequency since.

> Elated researchers shined their lights around the hilly prairie dog towns.

And finally, when the the word *shine* has the meaning *polish,* Americans almost always use *shined.*

Answer (score 3):

This [site](http://www.beedictionary.com/common-errors/shined_vs_shone) puts it pretty nicely:

> The transitive form of the verb “shine” is ”shined.” If the context describes something shining on something else, use “shined”: “He shined his flashlight on the skunk eating from the dog dish.” You can remember this because another sense of the word meaning “polished” obviously requires “shined”: “I shined your shoes for you.”When the shining is less active, many people would use “shone”: “The sun shone on the tomato plants all afternoon.” But some authorities prefer “shined” even in this sort of context: “The sun shined on the tomato plants all afternoon.”If the verb is intransitive (lacks an object) and the context merely speaks of the act of shining, the past tense is definitely “shone”: “The sun shone all afternoon” (note that nothing is said here about the sun shining on anything).

Thus, as your professor was shining it "on the ball", "shined" would be correct. IT's correct, because, as the above states,  "if the context describes something shining on something else", and your professor is shining "a light" on the ball. thus, "shined" is used here.

If you the professor was just a shining a light, not particularly on anything, it would be "shoned".

Comment: The site is right (at least for American English), but the conclusion you draw from it is wrong. **He shined the flashlight,** or **He shined my shoes,** but **The flashlight shone on the ball.** However, it is not the prepositional phrase **on the ball** which makes the verb transitive in the OPs sentence, but the direct object **flashlight.**

Comment: But, the site states, "if the context describes something shining on something else", and the OP's context definitely gives the context of a light shining on a ball

Comment: I see. I think I disagree with the site then; I believe the American rule is that you use *shined* for when the verb is transitive. I don't perceive any difference whatsoever between *The sun shone all afternoon* and *The sun shone on the flowers.* But I do agree with *He shined the flashlight on the ball.*

Comment: Here's some evidence for my position from Google Ngrams. In American English, [nearly half](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shined+his+flashlight%2Cshone+his+flashlight&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) the uses of the transitive *shined/shown his flashlight* are *shined,* but [very few of the uses](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shined+on%2C+shone+on&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) of the intransitive *shined on/shone on* are *shined*.

Answer (score 3):

The OED reports that the past participle of *shine* is "*shone*, (now especially in sense 8) *shined*."

The sense 8 to which the dictionary is referring is the following one:

> verb transitive. Put a polish on or give a shine to (shoes etc.).
>
> > M. French: They…sold newspapers, shined shoes, ran errands.

Comment: Judging from Google Ngrams (which show *shined* is used much less often in the U.K.), this is the British rule (exactly what you want from the OED).

Comment: The NOAD reports the following example: "His shoes were shined to perfection."

Comment: Agreed. In the U.S., you never use *shone* for the meaning *polished*. (And in the U.K., it appears that you use *polished* instead of *shined* for shoes. See the Ngram in my comment on the original post.) From Google Ngrams, I would guess that roughly half of Americans use *shined* only to mean *polished*, maybe another 40% use *shined* whenever the verb has a direct object, and maybe 10% always use *shined*. But this is wild speculation.

Answer (score 0):

The OED says *shined* was commonly used in England from 1300 to 1800, then gradually replaced by *shone*.  Maybe the Americans just kept the original?