# Is there a word which describes being unable to see the stars because of the brightness of the moon?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for something like "eclipsed" or "occulted", but caused by the brightness of the light rather than by anything solid being in the way.

Comment: ***"Outshone"***?

Comment: @PeterShor "Outshone" just means the moon was brighter than the stars; it doesn't imply that the extra brightness stops you seeing nearby stars.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can say that the stars are [*washed out*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wash%20out) by the moonlight:

> #### intransitive verb
>
> 1. to become depleted of color or vitality: [fade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fade)

Unlike *obscured*, which to me has a connotation of either covering, physical obstruction, or darkness, *washed out* paints a more appropriate picture, which is that there is **too much light**.

Comment: This is the only answer here that is not half-assed. (Other than the awesome "masked", which would be the technical or engineering choice.) (Err, other than the actual term used by astronomers, of course.)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best choice for what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, "washed out" is the standard astronomical term for the Moon brightening the sky (scattered light, as the Sun does) to the point that the stars are hard to see against the bright background (low contrast). That's why you don't see stars during daytime. The stars are just as bright as ever, but now so low contrast with the background sky that you can't see them.

Answer (score 9):

Obscured

Meaning (verb past tense): keep from being seen; conceal.

Example(s): 
The stars were obscured by the brightness of the full moon.
You might well wear sunglasses to prevent the glare of the sun from obscuring your view.

Synonyms: hide, conceal, cover, veil, shroud, screen, mask, cloak, cast a shadow over, shadow, envelop, mantle, block, block out, blank out, obliterate, eclipse, overshadow

Seems to fit the purpose?

Comment: “… but caused by the brightness of the light rather than by anything solid being in the way”. _Obscured_ can just as well (or better) mean that something, like clouds for example, is in the way.

Comment: I think, perhaps, your comment is *obscuring* the fact that it's a suitable answer without actually getting in the way of it...

Comment: If you use "obscure", you do have to make clear that it's the light that's doing the obscuring. If you just said "The stars were obscured by the moon", the most natural interpretation would be that the stars in question were physically behind the moon.

Answer (score 9):

The correct term in astronomy is obfuscate.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! It would be nice if you can include sources as well to make a better answer. It would be a nice addition to have astronomers or sky observers here :)

Comment: Google provides [However, as Space.com notes, the bright light of the moon will likely obfuscate the meteor shower’s full brilliance.](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/20670-meteor-shower-peaking-lyrids-to-appear-tonight/)

Comment: @Jorge .. you probably have seen this :)  http://www.xkcd.com/1371/

Comment: I've never seen "obfuscate" used in that sense (in astronomy). Is it supported by dictionaries?

Answer (score 6):

> "Outshone"

works well. Also the three sub-definitions add something
to the meaning ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outshine))

> ```
> (transitive) to shine more brightly than
> (transitive) to surpass in excellence, beauty, wit, etc
> (intransitive) (rare) to emit light
> ```

Comment: "Outshined" is non-standard. "Outshone" is the standard past tense and past participle.

Comment: @Tatpurusha [_Shine_](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/has-the-sun-shined-or-shone/) is one of those “strong verbs” that had an irregular past tense and past participle (_shone_) but later acquired a regular form ending in _-ed_ as well. Some people use the forms interchangeably, but there is a pattern that most people follow to keep them distinct. _Shined_ takes a personal subject and an object: _I shined the flashlight at the bear. Shone_ is used of light sources and does not take an object: _The moon shone over the harbor._

Comment: It may be [difficult to show *outshined* is the common usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outshone%2Coutshined&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutshone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutshined%3B%2Cc0), except perhaps in a shoe-shining competition

Comment: The difference between *shined* and *shone* in American English is [quite complicated](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39622/is-shined-correct-if-so-is-he-shined-x-on-the-tree-also-correct) (and depends on the speaker/dialect), but very few Americans use *shined* for either the sun or the moon.

Comment: I've edited my answer with outshone. I had found "outshined" in relation to cosmic bodies occulting stars in a letter to Haley  (the one from the comet) and more recently here http://www.space.com/11451-lyrid-meteor-shower-moon-skywatching-tips.html . So, I thought this form of participle was a an idomatic use in the field. I was wrong.

Comment: I don't think "outshone" works. "The moon outshone the stars", per the definition you give, just means that it's brighter than the stars. That is true but the asker wants to describe the particular case where some stars cannot be seen because the much brighter moon is nearby in the sky.

Answer (score 2):

*Blind* can be used also.

> The moonlight blinded the stars.

Technically, this is a *natural light pollution* (for night sky observers), especially when it is full moon.

---

Definition from [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blind):

> *v.t.* **19.** to outshine; eclipse: *a radiance that doth blind the sun.*

Comment: No, the moon might blind (dazzle) the _observer_, but it's not going to do a thing to the stars. That usage given is certainly not in use today.

Comment: @Phil: It is in use.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *bedim* and *dim*.

> [bedim](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bedim): to make [dim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dim)
>
> [dim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dim): to make dim or dimmer

*The stars are bedimmed by the moon*.

*The stars were dimmed by the moon*.

Comment: That's a very _obscure_ word.

Comment: @Mitch It surely is! :-)

Comment: They don't change in actual brightness, though.

Answer (score 1):

An easy term to use here is **[diluted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diluted)**.  In fact the example given by the dictionary is pretty close to your question.

> adjective:  made less strong or severe ("A pale gleam of diluted
>   sunlight")

You could also say that the moonlight *saturated* the sky, and if you want to be stylistic you could say that the moonlight *overshadowed/clouded* the stars.

Comment: No, the light from the stars has not been diluted (spread out into a lower concentration). Light from the Moon is scattered in the atmosphere (like sunlight), brightening the whole sky and reducing contrast between the stars and the background. The stars are just as bright as they were before.

Answer (score 1):

In audio, when one frequency becomes inaudible due to a stronger, near-by frequency signal, that is called Masking.

Comment: Welcome to ELU Dude! Can you please explain how this audio term is a fit for this question? Can it be used for light also?

Comment: Excellent answer - definitely the one I would use.

Comment: @erm .. "Can you please explain how this audio term is a fit for this question?" the most fundamental nature of human language is that you can abstract descriptions across classes. indeed, arguably this is the single central nature of human consciousness.  "Can it be used for light also?"  Yes, I just tried it and it's perfect.  Awesome answer!

Comment: I like it. "The stars were masked by the moon's brightness." Works for me. Going to go with "Washed out" though I think!

Comment: No, this can't be used for light. For light, "masking" refers to physically blocking the path of light, which is not the situation being asked about here. For example, computer chips are made photolithography, a process that shine light through a [photomask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomask) onto a light-sensitive compound. The light breaks down the compound, except for the masked (i.e., shadowed) areas. Likewise, a [shadow mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mask) in a CRT physically blocks light.

Answer (score 0):

When ground light drowns out the stars, it is called 'light pollution'.  I don't see  why the moon's light could not be described the same way.

Comment: Correct. I mentioned it already though :)

Comment: I think `light pollution` would generally give a sense that the cause is artificial light instead of natural ones

Comment: I'm really looking for an adjective. "Light pollutioned" doesn't work as well for me. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: "Pollution" very strongly implies man-made.

Comment: I disagree with David - natural effects can pollute too.  In the case of light pollution, it is the distinction between the dim light you want to see being dominated by a nearby brighter source, natural or man-made.  The sun is actually a huge offender, wiping out half of every day over the entire sky.

Comment: Oldcat, light pollution means artificial sources of light. See this http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/light-pollution The question is asking about not seeing stars because of the brightness of the moon, which does not involve artificial light.

Answer (score 0):

From dictionary.reference.com

obscure [uhb-skyoor ]

verb (used with object) [ob·scured, ob·scur·ing.]
1. to conceal or conceal by confusing (the meaning of a statement, poem, etc.).
2. to make dark, dim, indistinct, etc.
3. to reduce or neutralize (a vowel) to the sound usually represented by a schwa (ə).

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obscure?linkid=fp2lgd