# Outshone or outshined?

Tags: word-choice

I've tried to search whether I should use "outshined" or "outshone".

My spellcheck underlines "outshined", but dictionary.com suggests I can use either.  Which one should it be?

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outshined

Comment: See this [similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39622/is-shined-correct-if-so-is-he-shined-x-on-the-tree-also-correct) on *shined* versus *shone*. The short version: in the U.K. people generally use *shone* for everything except shoes. In the U.S., people generally use *shone* except for the transitive sense; for example, *"he shined his flashlight on the creature"*. Since *"outshine"* isn't used in that transitive sense, I'd recommend *"outshone"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use "outshone" as it is [used more often than "outshined"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outshined%2C+outshone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutshined%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutshone%3B%2Cc0).

**EDIT:** However this ngram may be inaccurate as there is [a song called "Outshined"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outshined).

Answer (score 3):

[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shine) gives the usage note I'd expect for the form 'shined' [past tense]:

> **shine**   vb, shines, shining or shone
>
> 1. (intr) to emit light
> 2. (intr) to glow or be bright with reflected light
> 3. (tr) to direct the light of (a lamp, etc): he shone the torch in my eyes.
> 4. (tr; past tense and past participle shined) to cause to gleam by polishing: to shine shoes.
> 5. ...

I'd say that this licenses 'outshined' only if you were comparing the efforts of two shoeshine boys or valets, or, in the US at least [see Peter's comment], indicating a greater proficiency in the use of a torch. Both of which seem marginal senses.

Comment: That's ***not*** what Collins says. As I interpret that entry, it says that either *shined* or *shone* is acceptable as a past tense ***except*** for polishing shoes. Otherwise, it would have specified *shone* for senses 1, 2, and 3. (What you recommend is indeed British usage, but Americans use *shined* for sense 3 as well, and occasionally for senses 1 and 2. I think Collins is trying to cover both sides of the Atlantic in the usage note.)

Comment: Yes, the dictionary is inaccurate here; 'shining or shone' makes no sense. I've added the other far-fetched possibility to reflect the 'US usage' (the term is reasonably meaningful in this case).

Comment: Actually, the online version of [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shine?showCookiePolicy=true) doesn't have the *or*, and says *"shone"* for British English, and "*shone*, *shined*" for American. So you're essentially correct.

Comment: @Peter These polyseme- (and as you indicate, region-) sensitive verb forms fascinate me. I'd say 'I speeded up.' but 'I sped up the hill.'. I'd not use the past simple form 'fit' for any sense. And yes, I'd only use 'shined' (and use only 'shined') for 'put a shine on'.

Comment: Also, it's fascinating to compare / contrast the two 'editions' of 'Collins' we've linked to. Very similar, but ...

Comment: Judging from this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shined+his+shoes%2Cpolished+his+shoes%2Cshine+his+shoes%2Cpolish+his+shoes&year_start=1900&year_end=2012&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshined%20his%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolished%20his%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshine%20his%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolish%20his%20shoes%3B%2Cc0), there are some people in the U.K. for whom the past tense of *"shine my shoes"* is *"polished my shoes"*.

Comment: In general, the 'polish' sense of 'shine' is rare to very rare over here, in my estimation. Though there is no choice with 'shoeshine boy'.