# The sun has shined/shone its shine?

Tags: past-tense, irregular-verbs

I'm working on some lyrics here, and I'm not sure what would be correct/best:

> After the sun has shined its shine

> After the sun has shone its shine

Google returns more results for the latter, but still I'm not completely sure. Seems like both are in fact correct?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? They're good for simple questions like these. For example, http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shine will give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Related question, [Is “shined” correct? If so, is “he shined X on the tree” also correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39622/is-shined-correct-if-so-is-he-shined-x-on-the-tree-also-correct).

Comment: Thanks. @AndyT. Seems like both forms are correct then. Which form would you prefer personally.

Comment: @Jesper - As a Brit, I prefer *shone*. *Shined* is more common in the US than the UK.

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [Is 'shined' correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39622/8019)

Comment: Also see *[Why do some words have two past tense forms (e.g. “dreamed” vs. “dreamt”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/104015/16052)*

Comment: While the links of choster and TimLymington are informative, they don't answer the OP's question.  They only address the preterit tense.  They do not address usage in relation to the past participle (has shined v. has shone).

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are grammatical:

- has shined
- has shone

Both "shined" and "shone" are past participles of the verb "[to shine](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/shine.html)."  As far as lyrics go, "shined it's shine" waxes more literary, in my humble opinion.