# What caused the spike in usage of Shone just before 1600?

Tags: history

I was looking at the usage of *shine* vs *shone* (related: [Is "shined" correct? If so, is "he shined X on the tree" also correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39622/is-shined-correct-if-so-is-he-shined-x-on-the-tree-also-correct)) and noticed that between about 1590-1600 *shone* has spiked in literary appearance.

[image]

What is the cause for this? I can speculate that some famous (at the time) literary work used it and it gained popularity, perhaps one of Shakespeare's.

Comment: The Great Comet of 1577 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of books that google have access to in 1595 (The source of the spike) is tiny, and the graph shows use of 'shone' **as a percent of all other n-grams recorded in that year**, a very small increase in the use of the word 'Shone' is enough to represent the spike that you see.

The N-Gram 'shone' was used a mere 6 times, in 2 books in google's 1595 dataset; the 'spike' isn't really that significant at all.  OCR is also a lot less reliable on very old texts, so some of these could be OCR errors, for 'stone' for instance.

The dataset for 'shone' in the 1590s is as follows:

`Year Count Number of books`

`1590   2   2`

`1593   2   1`

`1595   6   2`

`1598   2   1`

For context, the 1900 peak represent 18,005 uses of 'shone' in 5,166 books.

Comment: +1 This is why Google NGrams deprecates searches before 1800.

Comment: also because the OCR is much less accurate on older texts,  there's a massive spike of "jeff" in 1710, which is funny as the name basically didn't exist then, every single hit on google books is an OCR error, mostly for 'jest'/"jests"